# How do you replace content of multiple files at the same time in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The problem here is only the last file is being modified. But all of the files returns success messages. What's wrong with it? Thanks.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    fileArr = [
                'base/general.css',
                'components/bootstrap_icons.css',
                'components/fullpage_slider.css'
            ];

for(var key in fileArr) {
    fs.readFile(fileArr[key],'utf8', function(err,data) {
        if(err){
            return console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('success');
        }

        var result = data.replace(/([^\/][.*]|[(.]).*?(\bimages\b)/g,'(images');

        fs.writeFile(fileArr[key], result, 'utf8', function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a scoping issue.

By the time you are writing the files, `key` is already at the last point.

Try this instead:

```
for (var key in fileArr) {
    (function (file) {
        //new scope for this file
        fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('success');
            }

            var result = data.replace(/([^\/][.*]|[(.]).*?(\bimages\b)/g, '(images');

            fs.writeFile(file, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('success');
                }
            });
        });
    })(fileArr[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply use the Array.prototype.forEach() ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) without having to resort to a closure or an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression):

```
fileArr.forEach(function(file) {
    // do stuff
});
```